# INSERTED table really exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why I can use this select:

```
SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED
```

into a trigger, but not run like another select?

I got this error:

> Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>
> Invalid object name 'INSERTED'.

It works in this statement (that's inside a trigger):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INSERTED) AND
      NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM DELETED)
   BEGIN
      -- AFTER INSERT
      UPDATE VEIC
      SET
         VEIC.FLAG = 'I'
      FROM
         DBVEICULO VEIC
            INNER JOIN INSERTED INS ON INS.ID_VEICULO = VEIC.ID_VEICULO
```

Trigger > http://pastebin.com/9Dh4TUPc

Comment: Give us an example of what works, what doesn't work, and be specific with what you're asking please.

Comment: Do you actually have real table called INSERTED? Inside of a trigger that's a completely different story

Comment: Inserted is a special virtual table that only exists in triggers

Comment: If your version of SQL supports the `OUTPUT` clause, `inserted` is available with INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.  Although in that context `inserted` in considered a column prefix instead of a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[As per the documentation - Create Trigger (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx):

> DML triggers use the deleted and inserted logical (conceptual) tables. They are structurally similar to the table on which the trigger is defined, that is, the table on which the user action is tried. The deleted and inserted tables hold the old values or new values of the rows that may be changed by the user action. For example, to retrieve all values in the deleted table, use:

So the two tables, `INSERTED` and `DELETED`, only exists in the context of a trigger.